# Output the result of a mysql query, with multiple UNION, into CSV

Tags: mysql

I want to output the results of a query that uses multiple joins, group by and order by, into a CSV file.

The query itself generates the result-set, a blank row and a totals row using UNION.

When I try to output the file into a CSV using a UNION ALL, it gives the error

```
select "header1", "header2", "header3"
UNION ALL
(  
   select field1, field2, field3
   from tablename1
   UNION
   select "","",""
   UNION
   select "Total", field2, field3
)
into outfile 'c:\\data.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

```
Err 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (select "","","","","","","","","","","" ) ' at line <6>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `from table`: if your table name is `table` - then you need to quote it with backticks.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks for the comment, the table name is not table, I used it just as an example, sorry for the confusion... will edit it.

Comment: I don't think the error message is from this query.

Comment: Last Union there is a from missing

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't understand???

Comment: @DanielE. the query executes fine without the output options

Comment: I'm not even talking about the wrong number of columns. There is no code like `UNION (select ...)` in your query. So the error message can't be for this query.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel the query is the generic format of my live query `select field1, field2, field3
       from tablename
       UNION
       select "","",""
       UNION
       select "Total", field2, field3 from tablename` works fine

Comment: I've tested this query and it seems like your outer `UNION ALL` cannot union with the sub-query that contains those multiple unions. Is there a reason why you do it like that?

Comment: ( after union all is not necessary as is the matching brace.

Comment: @tcadidot0 please explain what do you mean by  **cannot union with the sub-query**. I have _equal number_ of headers and fields

Comment: @P.Salmon removing the opening and closing braces, as suggested by you, shifts the (same) error to the last line of the query

Comment: I just discovered that myself @burf. I saw your query and it doesn't seem to have a problem. I was also thinking the same thing as you are - equal number of headers and fields - suppose to work. I keep on changing the field inside the sub-query and assigning something like `AS "field_name"` but all I got is the same error. The only time I got the query working is when I run the sub-query individually OR without using `( and )` like P.Salmon mention. So, I'm curios if you have a particular reason to do it that way and maybe we can work out another way to solve it.

Comment: The reason for `UNION ALL` is to force the header row to be the first one.

Comment: @tcadidot0 first of all, thanks a lot to you for your help and efforts. I have absolutely no problem with any solution as long as I get a CSV file :-)

Comment: No problem @burf . I've tested Paul's answer and that worked. So you could try that and all the best to you ;)

Comment: @tcadidot0 yeah I did too and it works, thanks a lot for your help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that something like this:

```
select 1, 2, 3
union all
(
  select 0,4,6
  union
  select 1,1,1
)
```

will not work.

You should use a derived table like this instead:

```
select 1, 2, 3
union all
select * from (
  select 0,4,6
  union
  select 1,1,1
) x
```